# Change MySQL master to a slave

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, master-slave, slave

I have a MySQL master/slave configuration

```
 --------        --------  
| master |  ->  | slave1 |
 --------        --------
```

I want to kill my current master, transform slave1 to be the new master and have another slave pointing to slave1

```
 --------          ------------        --------
| master |        | new master |  ->  | slave2 |
 --------          ------------        --------
  KILLED
```

What is the best way to do this without database downtime?
I am using MariaDB 10.0.17

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonably easy as a MySQL server can be both a master and a slave at the same time.

I think a the process would go something like:

1. Stop replication from master to slave1.
2. Setup slave1 as master and replicate to slave2. When slave1 becomes the master then this will ensure events are replicated to slave2 as you would expect. You will also need to configure slave1 to write updates from the current master to it's binary log, else the initial replication will not be daisy chained. To do this you will need to add `log_slave_updates` to your config (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) on slave1. This step is important otherwise slave2 will not have replicated data from the current master during the transition. Do not actually start replication yet.
3. Take dump of slave1 and import to slave2 (alternatively you could hot copy and note log positions).
4. Start replication from slave1 to slave2 with your copied log positions.
5. Resume replication from master to slave1. If you have done this all correctly, slave2 should now be getting chained replications from the master.
6. Point all clients to slave1 (new master) instead of master.
7. Make sure slave1 has all changes from master and stop it receiving replication as a slave.
8. Retire original master. slave1 is now new master.

All clients should have an active server to read/write to at every stage of the process. No downtime needed.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I don't see a problem with point 1, as long as Slave1 isn't being used for Reads or any other process.

Comment: Well, if during this time the master crashes you're pretty much f*ed up.

Comment: @fancyPants You need to get a consistent snapshot of data to slave2. An easy way to do this is as above. However, if the OP has more stringent requirements then he can do a hot copy instead (as mentioned in point 3). OPs requirements were "no downtime", not "full redundancy throughout".

Comment: What I did was follow the instructions on http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html (taking slave1 as master) and having `log_slave_updates = on`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is easier than you think. You can build whole replication chains.

Just setup replication from slave1 to slave2, kill your current master and you're done.

Comment: Yes, you do have to turn it on. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates

Answer (score 0):

On SLAVE run below commands

1. STOP SLAVE IO_THREAD and wait until"STOP SLAVE IO_THREAD" show all binary files read.
2. STOP SLAVE
3. RESET MASTER